# Converting Fixed-Width File to .txt then the .txt to .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv, fixed-width

I have a fixed-width file that I have no issues importing and splitting into 31 txt files. The spaces from the fixed-width file are conserved in this process since the writing to the txt simply writes each entry from the fixed-width file as a new line.

My issue is that when I use python's csv function these spaces are replaced with "(a quotation mark) as a place holder.

I'm looking to see if there is a way to have a csv file produced without these double quotes as place holders while maintaining the required formatting initially set in the fixed-width file.

Initial line in txt doc:

```
'PAY90004100095206    9581400086000909  0008141000 5350 3810 C    000021841998051319980513P810406247                               FELT, MARTIN & FRAZIER, P.C.                                               FELT, MARTIN & FRAZIER, P.C.            208 NORTH BROADWAY STE 313                                  BILLINGS                 MT59101-0                            NLance Martin v. Whitman College                             N00000000NN98004264225  SYS656               19980512+000000378761998041319980421+000000378769581400086000909  000+000000                  Lance Martin v. Whitman College                             00000000        00010001                                 +00000000000002184                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            000000021023.005000000003921.005\n'
```

.py:

```
import csv

read_loc = 'c:/Users/location/e0290000005.txt'
e02ext_start = read_loc.find('e02')
e02_ext = read_loc[int(e02ext_start):]

with open(read_loc, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

dict_of_record_lists = {}

# takes first 3 characters of each line and if a matching dictionary key is found
# it appends the line to the value-list
for line in contents:
    record_type = (line[:3]) 
    dict_of_record_lists.setdefault(record_type,[]).append(line)


slice_list_CLM = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,47),(47,55),(55,59),(59,109),(109,189),(189,191),(191,193),(193,194),(194,195),(195,203),(203,211),(211,219),(219,227),(227,235),(235,237),(237,239),(239,241),(241,245),(245,249),(249,253),(253,257),(257,261),(261,291),(291,316),(316,331),(331,332),(332,357),(357,377),(377,378),(378,408),(408,438),(438,468),(468,470),(470,485),(485,505),(505,514),(514,517),(517,525),(525,533),(533,535),(535,536),(536,537),(537,545),(545,551),(551,553),(553,568),(568,572),(572,587),(587,602),(602,627),(627,631),(631,638),(638,642),(642,646),(646,654),(654,662),(662,670),(670,672),(672,674),(674,675),(675,676),(676,682),(682,700),(700,708),(708,716),(716,717),(717,725),(725,733),(733,741),(741,749),(749,759),(759,761),(761,762),(762,763),(763,764),(764,765),(765,768),(768,769),(769,770),(770,778),(778,779),(779,783),(783,787),(787,788),(788,805),(805,817),(817,829),(829,833),(833,863),(863,893),(893,896),(896,897),(897,898),(898,928),(928,936),(936,944),(944,945),(945,947),(947,959),(959,971),(971,983),(983,995),(995,1007),(1007,1019),(1019,1031),(1031,1043),(1043,1055),(1055,1067),(1067,1079),(1079,1091),(1091,1103),(1103,1115),(1115,1127),(1127,1139),(1139,1151),(1151,1163),(1163,1175),(1175,1187),(1187,1197),(1197,1202),(1202,1203),(1203,1211),(1211,1214),(1214,1215),(1215,1233),(1233,1241),(1241,1257),(1257,1272),(1272,1273),(1273,1285),(1285,1289),(1289,1293),(1293,1343),(1343,1365),(1365,1685),(1685,1686),(1686,1704),(1704,1708),(1708,1748),(1748,1768),(1768,1770),(1770,1772),(1772,1773),(1773,1782),(1782,1784),(1784,1792),(1792,1793),(1793,1796),(1796,1800)]
slice_list_CTL = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,23),(23,31),(31,39),(39,47),(47,55),(55,56),(56,65),(65,74),(74,83),(83,98),(98,113),(113,128),(128,143),(143,158),(158,173),(173,188),(188,203),(203,218),(218,233),(233,248),(248,263),(263,278),(278,293),(293,308),(308,323),(323,338),(338,353),(353,368),(368,383),(383,398),(398,413),(413,428),(428,443),(443,458),(458,473),(473,488),(488,503),(503,518),(518,527),(527,536),(536,545),(545,554),(554,563),(563,572),(572,581),(581,590),(590,599),(599,614),(614,623),(623,638),(638,647),(647,662),(662,671),(671,686),(686,695),(695,710),(710,719),(719,728),(728,737),(737,746),(746,755),(755,764),(764,773),(773,782),(782,791),(791,800),(800,809),(809,818),(818,827),(827,836),(836,845),(845,854),(854,863),(863,872),(872,881),(881,890),(890,899),(899,908)]
slice_list_ADR = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,50),(50,53),(53,62),(62,65),(65,66),(66,91),(91,111),(111,121),(121,151),(151,181),(181,206),(206,208),(208,223),(223,243),(243,261),(261,265),(265,283),(283,287),(287,305),(305,335),(335,375),(375,383),(383,387),(387,437),(437,438),(438,446),(446,454),(454,461),(461,468),(468,484),(484,500)]
slice_list_AGR = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,45),(45,85),(85,93),(93,101),(101,109),(109,117),(117,127),(127,139),(139,151)]
slice_list_ACN = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,65),(65,95),(95,115),(115,145),(145,165),(165,195),(195,215),(215,245),(245,265),(265,295),(295,315),(315,345),(345,365),(365,395),(395,415),(415,445),(445,465),(465,495),(495,515),(515,545),(545,565),(565,595),(595,615),(615,645),(645,665),(665,695),(695,715),(715,745),(745,765),(765,795),(795,815),(815,845),(845,865),(865,895),(895,915),(915,945),(945,965),(965,995),(995,1015),(1015,1045),(1045,1061)]
slice_list_CST = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,53),(53,59),(59,60),(60,61),(61,62),(62,64),(64,80),(80,82),(82,84),(84,86),(86,88),(88,104)]
slice_list_MCF = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,49),(49,79),(79,94),(94,159),(159,175),(175,191)]
slice_list_DD1 = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,46),(46,54),(54,62),(62,63),(63,69),(69,75),(75,81),(81,87),(87,93),(93,94),(94,95),(95,103),(103,111),(111,119),(119,126),(126,134),(134,143),(143,154),(154,162),(162,170),(170,178),(178,186),(186,194),(194,202),(202,205),(205,208),(208,210),(210,218),(218,220),(220,228),(228,230),(230,238),(238,240),(240,248),(248,250),(250,258),(258,274)]
slice_list_DES = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,1300),(1300,1316)]
slice_list_IBC = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,48),(48,50),(50,54),(54,55),(55,56),(56,81),(81,101),(101,121),(121,124),(124,125),(125,145),(145,146),(146,149),(149,152),(152,154),(154,179),(179,199),(199,219),(219,222),(222,224),(224,227),(227,230),(230,238),(238,249),(249,265),(265,281)]
slice_list_ICD = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,57),(57,63),(63,69),(69,75),(75,81),(81,87),(87,95),(95,103),(103,111),(111,114),(114,122),(122,125),(125,126),(126,142),(142,144),(144,152),(152,154),(154,162),(162,164),(164,172),(172,174),(174,182),(182,184),(184,192),(192,208)]
slice_list_LEG = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,53),(53,61),(61,65),(65,73),(73,81),(81,82),(82,90),(90,98),(98,133),(133,148),(148,163),(163,164),(164,172),(172,180),(180,181),(181,216),(216,256),(256,296),(296,326),(326,356),(356,381),(381,383),(383,398),(398,418),(418,438),(438,456),(456,474),(474,509),(509,549),(549,589),(589,619),(619,649),(649,674),(674,676),(676,691),(691,711),(711,731),(731,749),(749,767),(767,782),(782,790),(790,798),(798,806),(806,810),(810,818),(818,826),(826,834),(834,840),(840,849),(849,879),(879,888),(888,918),(918,920),(920,921),(921,923),(923,931),(931,939),(939,943),(943,944),(944,952),(952,960),(960,990),(990,1020),(1020,1050),(1050,1051),(1051,1086),(1086,1095),(1095,1135),(1135,1175),(1175,1205),(1205,1235),(1235,1260),(1260,1262),(1262,1277),(1277,1295),(1295,1304),(1304,1312),(1312,1328)]
slice_list_LD1 = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,65),(65,95),(95,125),(125,150),(150,152),(152,167),(167,187),(187,205),(205,223),(223,227),(227,252),(252,267),(267,279),(279,309),(309,339),(339,359),(359,361),(361,376),(376,396),(396,414),(414,439),(439,440),(440,448),(448,454),(454,456),(456,871),(471,472),(472,492),(492,522),(522,552),(552,572),(572,574),(574,589),(589,609),(609,627),(627,637),(637,645),(645,685),(685,686),(686,706),(706,714),(714,744),(744,774),(774,794),(794,796),(796,811),(811,831),(831,849),(849,879),(879,909),(909,929),(929,931),(931,946),(946,966),(966,984),(984,992),(992,1004),(1004,1024),(1024,1064),(1064,1081),(1081,1098),(1098,1106),(1106,1121),(1121,1122),(1122,1152),(1152,1153),(1153,1162),(1162,1170),(1170,1185),(1185,1190),(1190,1220),(1220,1238),(1238,1253),(1253,1283),(1283,1301),(1301,1302),(1302,1303),(1303,1333),(1333,1363),(1363,1388),(1388,1390),(1390,1405),(1405,1406),(1406,1436),(1436,1442),(1442,1462),(1462,1463),(1463,1478),(1478,1493),(1493,1533),(1533,1535),(1535,1538),(1538,1540),(1540,1556),(1556,1756)]
slice_list_LD2 = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,60),(60,78),(78,118),(118,148),(148,178),(178,203),(203,205),(205,220),(220,238),(238,256),(256,260),(260,270),(270,290),(290,300),(300,302),(302,322),(322,352),(352,377),(377,397),(397,398),(398,423),(423,424),(424,454),(454,455),(455,456),(456,458),(458,474)]
slice_list_LD3 = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,46),(46,71),(71,91),(91,92),(92,122),(122,152),(152,177),(177,179),(179,194),(194,197),(197,205),(205,213),(213,221),(221,229),(229,237),(237,297),(297,305),(305,313),(313,321),(321,329),(329,337),(337,345),(345,353),(353,361),(361,421),(421,429),(429,489),(489,497),(497,557),(557,617),(617,633)]
slice_list_NET = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,53),(53,61),(61,69),(69,77),(77,88),(88,99),(99,105),(105,135),(135,146),(146,152),(152,182),(182,193),(193,199),(199,229),(229,240),(240,246),(246,276),(276,287),(287,293),(293,323),(323,334),(334,340),(340,370),(370,381),(381,387),(387,417),(417,428),(428,434),(434,464),(464,475),(475,481),(481,511),(511,522),(522,528),(528,558),(558,569),(569,575),(575,605),(605,616),(616,622),(622,652),(652,663),(663,669),(669,699),(699,710),(710,716),(716,746),(746,757),(757,763),(763,793),(793,804),(804,810),(810,840),(840,851),(851,857),(857,887),(887,898),(898,904),(904,934),(934,945),(945,951),(951,981),(981,992),(992,998),(998,1028),(1028,1039),(1039,1047),(1047,1055),(1055,1061),(1061,1077),(1077,1087),(1087,1103)]
slice_list_NOT = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,47),(47,55),(55,63),(63,71),(71,77),(77,79),(79,1279),(1279,1295),(1295,1296),(1296,1312)]
slice_list_OFF = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,75),(75,78),(78,93),(93,105),(105,107),(107,115),(115,123),(123,131),(131,132),(132,148)]
slice_list_PAY = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,60),(60,61),(61,65),(65,73),(73,81),(81,89),(89,90),(90,130),(130,165),(165,205),(205,245),(245,275),(275,305),(305,330),(330,332),(332,347),(347,367),(367,368),(368,428),(428,429),(429,437),(437,438),(438,439),(439,450),(450,452),(452,455),(455,458),(458,473),(473,481),(481,493),(493,501),(501,509),(509,521),(521,539),(539,542),(542,549),(549,552),(552,562),(562,567),(567,627),(627,635),(635,643),(643,647),(647,651),(651,653),(653,654),(654,684),(684,692),(692,702),(702,713),(713,1034),(1034,1050),(1050,1066)]
slice_list_PRC = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,46),(46,51),(51,81),(81,84),(84,87),(87,95),(95,103),(103,119),(119,125),(125,131),(131,147)]
slice_list_ACR = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,51),(51,59),(59,71),(71,79),(79,91),(91,103),(103,119),(119,135)]
slice_list_REC = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,58),(58,71),(71,84),(84,97),(97,110),(110,123),(123,136),(136,149),(149,162),(162,175),(175,188),(188,201),(201,214),(214,227),(227,240),(240,253),(253,266),(266,279),(279,292),(292,305),(305,318),(318,331),(331,344),(344,357),(357,370),(370,383),(383,396),(396,409),(409,422),(422,435),(435,448),(448,461),(461,474),(474,487),(487,500),(500,513),(513,526),(526,539),(539,552),(552,565),(565,578),(578,591),(591,604),(604,617),(617,630),(630,643),(643,656),(656,669),(669,682),(682,695),(695,708),(708,721),(721,734),(734,747),(747,760),(760,773),(773,786),(786,799),(799,812),(812,825),(825,838),(838,851),(851,864),(864,877),(877,890),(890,903),(903,916),(916,929),(929,942),(942,955),(955,968),(968,981),(981,997)]
slice_list_RED = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,57),(57,69),(69,81),(81,93),(93,105),(105,117),(117,129),(129,141),(141,157)]
slice_list_REI = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,61),(61,67),(67,87),(87,88),(88,100),(100,108),(108,116),(116,176),(176,192),(192,193),(193,199),(199,214),(214,222),(222,230),(230,238),(238,250),(250,251),(251,311),(311,327)]
slice_list_RES = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,46),(46,54),(54,134),(134,136),(136,148),(148,160),(160,172),(172,184),(184,196),(196,208),(208,220),(220,232),(232,242),(242,252),(252,262),(262,272),(272,282),(282,292),(292,299),(299,309),(309,319),(319,329),(329,339),(339,349),(349,359),(359,369),(369,379),(379,389),(389,399),(399,409),(409,419),(419,429),(429,439),(439,449),(449,465),(465,475),(475,975),(975,991)]
slice_list_RST = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,53),(53,61),(61,69),(69,77),(77,87),(87,95),(95,125),(125,145),(145,161),(161,177)]
slice_list_SPC = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,53),(53,61),(61,69),(69,77),(77,85),(85,93),(93,101),(101,109),(109,117),(117,125),(125,133),(133,149)]
slice_list_SSN = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,54),(54,62),(62,74),(74,82),(82,94),(94,102),(102,114),(114,122),(122,134),(134,142),(142,143),(143,151),(151,159),(159,160),(160,168),(168,176),(176,177),(177,185),(185,193),(193,194),(194,202),(202,210),(210,211),(211,219),(219,220),(220,228),(228,268),(268,276),(276,277),(277,293)]
slice_list_WRK = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,53),(53,57),(57,72),(72,73),(73,81),(81,82),(82,90),(90,98),(98,106),(106,114),(114,122),(122,130),(130,131),(131,132),(132,133),(133,153),(153,154),(154,155),(155,159),(159,179),(179,180),(180,240),(240,248),(248,256),(256,264),(264,272),(272,280),(280,284),(284,288),(288,298),(298,314),(314,330)]
slice_list_WD1 = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,54),(54,58),(58,59),(59,60),(60,61),(61,63),(63,73),(73,74),(74,82),(82,83),(83,91),(91,99),(99,107),(107,108),(108,118),(118,120),(120,130),(130,137),(137,139),(139,149),(149,156),(156,158),(158,168),(168,175),(175,177),(177,187),(187,194),(194,196),(196,206),(206,213),(213,223),(223,233),(233,243),(243,253),(253,263),(263,273),(273,283),(283,293),(293,303),(303,311),(311,314),(314,322),(322,332),(332,342),(342,352),(352,353),(353,354),(354,355),(355,365),(365,375),(375,385),(385,395),(395,405),(405,415),(415,425),(425,435),(435,436),(436,437),(437,438),(438,439),(439,440),(440,442),(442,443),(443,444),(444,445),(445,446),(446,448),(448,458),(458,460),(460,470),(470,472),(472,482),(482,484),(484,494),(494,496),(496,506),(506,508),(508,518),(518,528),(528,542),(542,543),(543,551),(551,559),(559,561),(561,565),(565,567),(567,574),(574,582),(582,583),(583,584),(584,585),(585,593),(593,594),(594,595),(595,596),(596,604),(604,605),(605,606),(606,607),(607,615),(615,616),(616,617),(617,618),(618,626),(626,627),(627,628),(628,629),(629,637),(637,645),(645,653),(653,661),(661,669),(669,677),(677,685),(685,693),(693,701),(701,709),(709,717),(717,721),(721,729),(729,732),(732,734),(734,738),(738,746),(746,749),(749,751),(751,755),(755,763),(763,766),(766,774),(774,782),(782,790),(790,798),(798,800),(800,801),(801,802),(802,813),(813,829)]
slice_list_WD3 = [(0,3),(3,7),(7,15),(15,21),(21,39),(39,42),(42,45),(45,46),(46,47),(47,48),(48,49),(49,50),(50,51),(51,52),(52,53),(53,54),(54,55),(55,56),(56,57),(57,58),(58,98),(98,138),(138,178),(178,182),(182,183),(183,191),(191,197),(197,213)]


slice_dict = {
'CLM' : slice_list_CLM,
'CTL' : slice_list_CTL,
'ADR' : slice_list_ADR,
'AGR' : slice_list_AGR,
'ACN' : slice_list_ACN,
'CST' : slice_list_CST,
'MCF' : slice_list_MCF,
'DD1' : slice_list_DD1,
'DES' : slice_list_DES,
'IBC' : slice_list_IBC,
'ICD' : slice_list_ICD,
'LEG' : slice_list_LEG,
'LD1' : slice_list_LD1,
'LD2' : slice_list_LD2,
'LD3' : slice_list_LD3,
'NET' : slice_list_NET,
'NOT' : slice_list_NOT,
'OFF' : slice_list_OFF,
'PAY' : slice_list_PAY,
'PRC' : slice_list_PRC,
'ACR' : slice_list_ACR,
'REC' : slice_list_REC,
'RED' : slice_list_RED,
'REI' : slice_list_REI,
'RES' : slice_list_RES,
'RST' : slice_list_RST,
'SPC' : slice_list_SPC,
'SSN' : slice_list_SSN,
'WRK' : slice_list_WRK,
'WD1' : slice_list_WD1,
'WD3' : slice_list_WD3,  
    }


def slicer(file,slice_list):
    csv_string = ""
    for i in slice_list:
        csv_string += (file[i[0]:i[1]]+",")
    return csv_string


overview_loc = 'c:/Users/location/E02_ingestion/'+ 'overview_'+e02_ext #put in file location wehre you would like to see logs
with open(overview_loc, 'w') as overview_file:
    for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
        overview_file.write((key+' '+(str(len(value)))+'\n'))

for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
    for k, v in slice_dict.items():
        if key == k:
            iteration = 0
            for i in value:
                s = slicer(i,v)
                value[iteration] = s
                iteration+= 1        

e02_ext = read_loc[int(e02ext_start):]
csv_ext = e02_ext[:-3]+'csv'


# file overview/log that shows how many lines should exist in the other files to ensure everything wrote correctly
overview_loc = 'c:/Users/location/E02_ingestion/'+ 'overview_'+e02_ext #put in file location wehre you would like to see logs
with open(overview_loc, 'w') as overview_file:
    for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
        overview_file.write((key+' '+(str(len(value)))+'\n'))

# if the list isn't empty writes a new file w/prefix matching key and includes the lines
for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
    write_loc = 'c:/Users/location/E02_ingestion/'+ key +'_'+e02_ext 
    with open(write_loc, "w", newline='') as parsed_file:
        for line in value:
            line_pre = "%s\n" % line
            parsed_file.write(line_pre[:-1])     


for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
    write_loc = 'c:/Users/location/E02_ingestion/'+ key +'_'+csv_ext 
    with open(write_loc, "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for i in value:
            writer.writerow(i)
```

This is a sample of a section of output in both Excel and our SQL table:

```
P A Y    9 0 0 0     4 1 0 0 0 9 5 2     0 7 " " " " " " " "
```

Desired output (void of " as place holders for spaces):

```
P A Y    9 0 0 0     4 1 0 0 0 9 5 2     0 7
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be beneficial to post a [mcve] including hardcoded data. I have no urge to reverse engenier your bad output through your code to get to your sourcedata to fix our problem to begin with. If you make it hard to help, you'll get less help - simple as that.

Comment: Added full code let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to change the initial text writing portion to:

```
for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
write_loc = 'c:/Users/Steve Barnard/Desktop/Git_Projects/E02_ingestion/'+ key +'_'+csv_ext 
with open(write_loc, "w", newline='') as parsed_file:
    for line in value:
        line_pre = "%s" % line
        parsed_file.write(line_pre[:-1]+'\n')
```

All the issues were fixed by avoiding python's built-in CSV writer.
The way my program added a comma following the line slices, left with one additional comma and the '\n'; this led the [:-1] slice in the write function to remove the \n and not the final ','. by adding the  '\n' following the comma removal the entire problem was fixed and a functioning CSV that retained the spacing was created.

A text file can be created by swapping out the extension upon writing.

Answer (score 0):

**Why:**

The problem you are facing is, that you have list entries inside your `row` of processed data that only contain the `csv.delimiter` character. The module then *quotes* them to distinguish your *"delimiter-only-data"* from your *"delimiter between columns"*.

When writing something like `[ ["PAY","...."," "," "," "," "] ]` into a csv using `' '` as divider you get them outputted quoted:

import csv

```
dict_of_record_lists = {"K": [ ["PAY","...."," "," "," "," "] ] }

for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
    write_loc = 't.txt'
    with open(write_loc, "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for i in value:
            writer.writerow(i)

print( open(write_loc).read())   #   PAY .... " " " " " " " "
```

**Fix**:

You can fix that specifying `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` and provide a `escapechar = ...` or by fixing your data. Providing an escapechar would put that into your file though.

Relevant portions of the documentation: [csv.QUOTE_NONE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE).

You can manipulate your data to **not** contain "only" the delimiters as data:

```
for key, value in dict_of_record_lists.items():
    write_loc = 'c:/Users/location/E02_ingestion/'+ key +'_'+csv_ext 
    with open(write_loc, "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for i in value:
            # if an inner item only contains delimiter characters, set it to empty string
            cleared = [x for x in i if i.strip(" ") else ""]
            writer.writerow(cleared)
```

HTH

Doku:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html